# processing a list of strings to remove duplicates and add corresponding value

Tags: string, python-2.7, python-3.x, list, pandas

I have a csv containing around 10k(10,000) rows like the following:

```
1: ['Andhra Pradesh-133', 'Meetai-1358', 'Meetai-2146', 'Meetai-2277']   
...
N: ['Andhra Pradesh-20', 'Rajasthan-60', 'Rajasthan-70']
```

I have to combine repeated values, for example:

```
['Andhra Pradesh-133', 'Meetai-5781'] // 5781 = 1358 + 2146 + 2277
```

Can any one suggest a quick way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `list comprehension` with `groupby`:

```
from  itertools import groupby


df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[['Andhra Pradesh-133', 'Meetai-1358', 'Meetai-2146', 'Meetai-2277'],
                        ['Andhra Pradesh-20', 'Rajasthan-60', 'Rajasthan-70']]}) 


data = []
for x in df['a']:
  b = [a.split('-') for a in x]
  L = [t for k, g in groupby(b, key=lambda x: x[0]) 
         for t in [k + '-' + str(sum((int(j) for i, j in g)))]]
  data.append(L)

print (data)

[['Andhra Pradesh-133', 'Meetai-5781'], ['Andhra Pradesh-20', 'Rajasthan-130']]

df['b'] = data
print (df)

                                                   a  \
0  [Andhra Pradesh-133, Meetai-1358, Meetai-2146,...   
1    [Andhra Pradesh-20, Rajasthan-60, Rajasthan-70]   

                                    b  
0   [Andhra Pradesh-133, Meetai-5781]  
1  [Andhra Pradesh-20, Rajasthan-130]
```

EDIT:

Solution if input is file:

```
data = []
for line in open('file.csv'):
    #strip new-line characters, split by [ and get second list
    items = line.strip('\r\n" ]').split('[')[1] 
    #split lines, remove whitespace
    items = [item.strip("' ") for item in items.split(',')] 
    #split to sublist
    items = [a.split('-') for a in items]
    #sum splitted sublists 
    items = [t for k, g in groupby(items, key=lambda x: x[0]) 
               for t in [k + '-' + str(sum((int(j) for i, j in g)))]]
    data.append(items)

print (data)
[['Andhra Pradesh-133', 'Meetai-5781'], ['Andhra Pradesh-20', 'Rajasthan-130']]
```

EDIT:

You need split by first occurence of `[` and then strip `[]` too:

```
data = []
for line in open('file.csv'):
    #strip new-line characters, split by [ and get second list
    items = line.strip('\r\n" ]').split('[', 1)[1] 
    #split lines, remove whitespace
    items = [item.strip("'[] ") for item in items.split(',')] 
    #split to sublist
    items = [a.split('-') for a in items]
    print (items)
    #sum splitted sublists 
    items = [t for k, g in groupby(items, key=lambda x: x[0]) 
               for t in [k + '-' + str(sum((int(j) for i, j in g)))]]
    data.append(items)
```

Comment: have a small doubt here if i consider x=[['panjim-20', 'Uttar Pradesh-23185', 'Gujurat-1013', 'Uttar Pradesh-51'] the statement function group by does not seem to work .
b = [a.split('-') for a in x]  for k,g in groupby(b, key=lambda x: x[0]): does not group by 'uttar Pradesh' also the string is exactly the same. could you help as to what must be the miss?

Comment: I think there is problem double `[[`. I edit answer.

Comment: apologies for the typo x=['panjim-20', 'Uttar Pradesh-23185', 'Gujurat-1013', 'Uttar Pradesh-51'] is the list i am trying to process. ?

Comment: You need `sorted` like `x=['panjim-20', 'Uttar Pradesh-23185', 'Gujurat-1013', 'Uttar Pradesh-51']`
`items = [a.split('-') for a in x]`
`a = [t for k, g in groupby(sorted(items), key=lambda x: x[0]) for t in [k + '-' + str(sum((int(j) for i, j in g)))]]`

Answer (score 0):

I would create a dict for each row. Parse the string-numbers by splitting or using a regex. The string e.g. 'Andhra Pradesh' is the key, the value is an int. Add the numbers to the value of the dict entry determined by the string.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the fastest way to do it, but this works for me:

```
data = [
  ['Andhra Pradesh-133', 'Meetai-1358', 'Meetai-2146', 'Meetai-2277'],
  ['Andhra Pradesh-20','Rajasthan-60','Rajasthan-70']
]

values = {}
for row in data:
  for x in row:
    tokens = x.split('-')
    values[tokens[0]] = int(tokens[1]) if tokens[0] not in values else values[tokens[0]] + int(tokens[1])
  out = [x + '-' + str(y) for x,y in values.iteritems()]

print out # prints: ['Andhra Pradesh-153', 'Meetai-5781', 'Rajasthan-130']
```

Answer (score 0):

In Pandas you could do

```
In [3475]: L = ['Andhra Pradesh-133', 'Meetai-1358', 'Meetai-2146', 'Meetai-2277']

In [3476]: s = (pd.DataFrame(x.split('-') for x in L)
                  .assign(v=lambda x: x[1].astype(int))
                  .groupby(0)['v'].sum())

In [3478]: (s.index + '-' + s.values.astype(str)).tolist()
Out[3478]: ['Andhra Pradesh-133', 'Meetai-5781']
```

---

Details

```
In [3480]: pd.DataFrame(x.split('-') for x in L)
Out[3480]:
                0     1
0  Andhra Pradesh   133
1          Meetai  1358
2          Meetai  2146
3          Meetai  2277
```

Column `1` is type `str`, we are `assign`ing column `v` with type `int`

```
In [3481]: pd.DataFrame(x.split('-') for x in L).assign(v=lambda x: x[1].astype(int))
Out[3481]:
                0     1     v
0  Andhra Pradesh   133   133
1          Meetai  1358  1358
2          Meetai  2146  2146
3          Meetai  2277  2277

In [3479]: s
Out[3479]:
0
Andhra Pradesh     133
Meetai            5781
Name: v, dtype: int32
```